# How to get name fields exist of model in Odoo(OpenERP)?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

Please, help me. I have a model 'res.users'. I want to get name fields exist(declared) in my model. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is not much clear what you want to do with that, but if you want to get the name of the model then you should go for below answer.

It's good if you can elaborate your question with output or few more details.

you should try following,

```
model = self.env['ir.model'].search([('model','=','res.users')])
if model:
    print model.name
```

However you can access all the fields of that model. There is field_id (one2many) field is there in **ir.model**.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, I think you want to check the **name** field exists in values or not.
So, while you write any method you can check it with a small block of code.
Like:

```
if 'name' in vals:
    "You block of CODE"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you would like to know what field is considered as the name field (as it could be modified using _rec_name when declaring the class). I think that you just need to check ._rec_name, based on this piece of code of models.py that do the opposite:

```
# validate rec_name
if cls._rec_name:
    assert cls._rec_name in cls._fields, \
        "Invalid rec_name %s for model %s" % (cls._rec_name, cls._name)
elif 'name' in cls._fields:
    cls._rec_name = 'name'
elif 'x_name' in cls._fields:
    cls._rec_name = 'x_name'
```